# Reading SMS info using NLP

Tags: nlp, data-science

I have a set of unclassified SMS messages from which I want to extract transaction related messages, then classify them on the basis of debit or credit. I will also want to extract the amount of transaction, its date and beneficiary as well.

Is there any way to approach this problem in NLP? I do not want to regexp match as my SMS database can be varied including e-wallet, cash transfer, ATM withdrawal, e-fund transfer and other such things with multiple providers.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you were trying to write. I will help with the English, however the question is too broad and not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself and come here only when you have a specific problem/error, then show us the code and data in a reproducible example.

Comment: @Hack-R From StackOverflows question asking guide, Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program!

There could be issues with my language but I do not find issue with this question itself.

Comment: Your question is too broad, off-topic, and needs a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example. I have voted to close it. I realize you are new to Stack Overflow, but this is pretty obvious. **Please review How to Ask and the MCVE guidelines**. *Stack Overflow is not a forum.*

Comment: I think this is a good question. Can you add a few examples @Akshat?

Comment: Hi @Daniel I think I have found a way out using these papers. I can look for solution.
http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jce/papers/Conf-%20ICFTE%E2%80%9916/Volume-1/12.%2072-79.pdf?id=7557

http://repositorio.pucrs.br/dspace/bitstream/10923/7249/1/000468523-Texto%2BCompleto-0.pdf

Comment: @Daniel In my usecase I wants to found out how much a user have transacted by reading his SMSs. Please provide more insight incase you can help me it

Comment: Provide examples, otherwise I can't offer any help.

Comment: @Daniel One of the example could be "Your a/c no. xxxxxxx1234 has been debited with $50.00 on 18 Sep 2017 15:45 with reference id xxxx987 for payment at McDonald. Clr Bal: $41276.00".
Here the info for my use is :- a). Transaction value :- $50 b). Transaction Type :- Debit c). Time :- 18 Sep 2017 15:45 d). Pupose :- McDonald Eatery e). Final Balance :- $41276.00 f). Associated Account :- xxxxxxx1234.

 The problem is that every bank or credit provided might have their own way of representing this data.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you can do

- Check spacy library which can help you with Named entity and money related extraction. I still feel that if you are talking about automated sms it might be better to use regex to extract these details.
- I am not sure what you mean by debit or credit

Comment: Thanks @Shrikar I mean transaction messages from my savings account.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is a hard problem, given the complexity the inputs generated. Here is what CogCompNLP is able to mine about your input: 
[image]

You can see that it is sensitive to dates and organizations.

> a). Transaction value :- $50 b). Transaction Type :- Debit c). Time :-
>   18 Sep 2017 15:45 d). Pupose :- McDonald Eatery e). Final Balance :-
>   $41276.00 f). Associated Account :- xxxxxxx1234.

What I would do is to combine a bunch of rules with these automatically extracted labels. Unfortunately there is no 100% guarantee about extraction of these labels, however if it works in 99% of your examples, then it should be reliable enough.

You can play with the demo here: http://nlp.cogcomp.org

Disclosure: I am one of the authors of this software.